# Adding data to existing h5py file along new axis using h5py

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have some sample code that generates a 3d Numpy array -- I am then saving this data into a h5py file using h5 file. How can I then "append" the second dataset along the 4th dimension? Or, how can I write another 3d dataset along the 4th dimension (or new axis) of an existing `.h5` file? I have read documentation that I could find, and none of the examples seem to address this. My code is shown below:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

dataset1 = np.random.rand(240,240,250);
dataset2 = np.random.rand(240,240,250);

with h5py.File('data.h5', 'w') as hf:
    dset = hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=dataset1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html I experimented a bit:

```
In [504]: import h5py
In [505]: f=h5py.File('data.h5','w')
In [506]: data=np.ones((3,5))
```

Make an ordinary `dataset`:

```
In [509]: dset=f.create_dataset('dset', data=data)
In [510]: dset.shape
Out[510]: (3, 5)
In [511]: dset.maxshape
Out[511]: (3, 5)
```

Help for `resize`:

```
In [512]: dset.resize?
Signature: dset.resize(size, axis=None)
Docstring:
Resize the dataset, or the specified axis.

The dataset must be stored in chunked format; it can be resized up to
the "maximum shape" (keyword maxshape) specified at creation time.
The rank of the dataset cannot be changed.
```

Since I didn't specify `maxshape` it doesn't look like I can change or add to this dataset.

```
In [513]: dset1=f.create_dataset('dset1', data=data, maxshape=(2,10,10))
...
ValueError: "maxshape" must have same rank as dataset shape
```

So I can't define a 3d 'space' and put a 2d array in it - at least not this way.

But I can add a dimension (rank) to `data`:

```
In [514]: dset1=f.create_dataset('dset1', data=data[None,...], maxshape=(2,10,10))
In [515]: dset1
Out[515]: <HDF5 dataset "dset1": shape (1, 3, 5), type "<f8">
```

Now I can resize the dataset - in 1 or more dimensions, up to the defined max.

```
In [517]: dset1.resize((2,3,10))
In [518]: dset1
Out[518]: <HDF5 dataset "dset1": shape (2, 3, 10), type "<f8">
In [519]: dset1[:]
Out[519]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

The original `data` occupies a corner of the expanded dataset

Now fill in some zeros:

```
In [521]: dset1[1,:,:]=10
In [523]: dset1[0,:,5:]=2

In [524]: dset1[:]
Out[524]: 
array([[[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   2.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   2.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   2.]],

       [[ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
        [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
        [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,  10.]]])
```

So yes, you can put both of your `dataset` in one `h5` dataset, provided you specified a large enough `maxshape` to start with, e.g. (2,240,240,250) or (240,240,500) or (240,240,250,2) etc.

Or for unlimited resizing `maxshape=(None, 240, 240, 250))`.

Looks like the main constraint is you can't added a dimension after creation.

Another approach is to concatenate the data before storing, e.g.

```
dataset12 = np.stack((dataset1, dataset2), axis=0)
```